# Simple conversion question Aspx to Razor (Ascx -> Cshtml)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I´m trying to convert that:

```
<%
    var obj = Model.Div;
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var lockpopup<%=obj %> = null;
   function call<%=obj %>(<%=JsTools.MakeParameters(Model.Parameters) %>) { 
      if(lockpopup<%=obj %> != null) return;
   }
```

to Razor synthax...

Thanks

Comment: is `lockpopup<%=o %>` a mistake? I see only `obj` and no `o`.

Comment: What's this code supposed to do? It looks bad. Maybe you should fix it before converting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My completely untested guess.

```
@{
  var obj = Model.Div;
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var lockpopup@obj = null;
    function call@obj (@(JsTools.MakeParameters(Model.Parameters))) { 
      if(lockpopup@obj != null) return;
    }
  </script>
}
```

And in retrospect, I don't see how declaring `obj` is helpful. It adds a layer of indirection. Why not simply?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lockpopup@(Model.Div) = null;
  function call@(Model.Div) (@(JsTools.MakeParameters(Model.Parameters))) { 
    if(lockpopup@(Model.Div) != null) return;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: As opposed to simply using `@var obj = Model.Div` ? Best reason I can find is that Intellisense works then. :)